# MediaPlayer pause called in state 8 when player is playing

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm desperate, I work with MediaPlayer and I would just pause the player.
But when I try to pause the player, I got error (-38, 0).
And in log : pause called in state 8.

I know this error would mean I try to pause the player when it isn't started. But my code is :

```
if (mediaMusic.isPlaying()) {
        Log.d("GREG", "Media music is playing");
        mediaMusic.pause();
        Log.e("GREG", "Media music paused");
}
```

But in logs :

```
D/GREG: Media music is playing
V/MediaPlayer-JNI: pause
V/MediaPlayer: pause
E/MediaPlayer: pause called in state 8, mPlayer(0x7546266e00)
V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=100, ext1=-38, ext2=0
E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
V/MediaPlayer: callback application
V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
E/GREG: Media music paused
```

So if somebody has an idea to resolve this issue it will be beautiful !

Thanks !

EDIT : I've just see the problem is only present when I set the speed of MediaPlayer like that

```
mediaMusic.setPlaybackParams(mediaMusic.getPlaybackParams().setSpeed(rate));
```

But I have to change the speed, so the problem is still unsolved ...

Comment: Did you try first set standard speed and then call pause? (not the best solution, but anyway)

Comment: I've already set the speed before call pause if is what you want say (sorry I dont speak english very well).

Comment: I mean setSpeed(1.0) and after that mediaMusic.pause() - does it produce error too?